# How to use external stuff like Marshaller in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, external

If I want to use something like http://www.castor.org/javadoc/org/exolab/castor/xml/Marshaller.html in Eclipse how do I do this? Having

```
import org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller;
```

doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure what to search to find out what to use. Is Marshaller an external library, or package, or a classpath, or a plugin? I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the library this class belongs to (use [JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com)), download the jar and add it to the build path of your project, using

> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> <select from the location where you downloaded the jar to>

The class you referred to in your question seems to be from [Castor Java XML Binding](http://www.castor.org/download.html) library, so download the jar from their site and follow the steps above. Then the import statement would work without throwing any errors.